# Netsuite / Freemarker - accessing transaction line level data in email template

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I'm trying to take a current email template that my organization uses to request an order deposit based on the customer's current pending transaction so freemarker works fine to grab ${transaction.tranId} and such.

I have a new requirement to grab a transaction line level hyperlink and send it out with the email request, but I only want to send it if that data exists and only for the items that the link applies to.

```
<#if (record.item.custcol1)?has_content>

    <p><strong>Please re-review the following artwork proof link(s) associated with your order:</strong></p>

    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as item>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th align="left" colspan="3" style="padding: 10px 6px;">${item.custcol1@label}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.custcol1}</td>
        </tr>
        </#list><!-- end items -->
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr style="width: 100%; color: #d3d3d3; background-color: #d3d3d3; height: 1px;" /></#if>
```

I can't seem to access the line level data in the same way that I would in a PDF form. I've tried the code without the if statement on a known record where I know I have data to access but it won't pull the fields into the email.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly and understanding your requirement, you should have the `<#if>` block inside the `<#list>` - you want to test the contents of a field on each item, rather than the whole item list as one block.  Also, `record.item.custcol1` would be invalid - you would need to provide an index for the item to test, eg: `record.item[0].custcol1` if that's what you're intending.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `<#list>` should only be around the table rows, like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th align="left" colspan="3" style="padding: 10px 6px;">${item.custcol1@label}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <#list record.item as item>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.custcol1}</td>
        </tr>
        </#list>
    </tbody>
</table>
```